# configure an offline file system on linux

Tags: linux, samba, offline-files

I would like to reinstall an old laptop to be able to synchronize seamlessly with my NAS. This NAS provides Samba shares.

The purpose is to be on the field with my laptop and my data and when I'm back to my home-network, the data on the laptop and the NAS are synchronized.

I'm looking for a system really similar to the Windows OFfline files mechanism. But on Linux. Whether Linux native or easily configurable. I'm a Linux newbie (this would be my 1st Linux installation).

Is this possible in an easy way with Linux ?

I've googled a lot on the subject but could not find any clear answer.

Comment: Please check the revision, if it is up to your standards. However, I'm looking for a recommendation, an advice. So I'm afraid, I won't be in the standards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this has already been answered on SuperUser by using cachefilesd on linux. https://superuser.com/a/446711/894385

But realistically, if you aren't sure which Linux Distribution you would like to use the easiest solution will to be reinstall with Windows 7. The native Windows offline files mechanism is going to be much more stable as you are working with an SMB share on your NAS.  There are some older reports of issues with using cachefilesd in combination with cifs(smb) shares though because they are older the kernel support should be available in newer distributions.  Here is an example of one such problem on CentOS https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=1941

Comment: I'll stick to to Win7 for the moment. I'll experiment with Linux (Mint?) at another time.